# How do I make slideshow appear by default?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am unable to make a slideshow appear by default on my website.
This is what I'm trying to get : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow (but with 2 photos instead of 3)

However, this is what I am getting: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBpQa.png)

The photos only appear when i click the left or right arrows

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
html{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    flex: 1;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

 
  


body{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgb(35, 166, 252), white);
}





* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
 
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="mypast.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="mypast.js"></script>
    
    <h1>MY PAST</h1>
    <div class="topnav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
          <a href="mypast.html">My Past</a>
          <a href="mypresent.html">My Present</a>
          <a href="myfuture.html">My Future</a>
          <a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
      <img src="friends.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption one</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
      <img src="badmintonteam.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="text">Caption two</div>
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
       
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('yourNextSliderbuttonID').click();
},1000); // the button will be clicked every 1000milisec/1 sec`enter code here`